# CSV file from firebase storage with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, csv, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to get a CSV file from firebase storage, then parse it so I can send data to the right documents in firestore. I had a working function, but I don't know why. This is the code that should parse the CSV data. Currently, I get undefined in the data constant, so I think the data from the csv gets converted to utf8 incorrectly. However, it used to run before.

```
exports.importCSVAppointments = functions.region('europe-west3').storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {
  const name = object.name;
  //Test if file is in correct folder and is csv file
  const nameSplit = name.split('/');
  const organisation = nameSplit[1].split('_')[1];
  const folder = nameSplit[0];
  if(folder == 'imports'){
    //Retrieve the file from firebase storage
    const storage = new Storage();
    const bucket = storage.bucket('gs://fmis-online-dev.appspot.com');
    admin.storage().bucket().file(name)
      .download(function (err, contents) {
          if (!err) {
            const convert = (from, to) => str => Buffer.from(str, from).toString(to);
            const hexToUtf8 = convert('hex', 'utf8');
            const data = hexToUtf8(contents);
            const dataSplit = data.split('\n');
            console.log(dataSplit);
            for(i=1;i<=dataSplit.length-1;i++){
              console.log('actually runs');
              //This will run for every appointment

              //Get appointment data
              const text = dataSplit[i];
              const parsedData = text.match( /\s*(\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^,]+)\s*(,|$)/g ).map( function (text) {
                let m;
                if (m = text.match(/^\s*\"(.*?)\"\s*,?$/)) return m[1]; // Double Quoted Text
                if (m = text.match(/^\s*'(.*?)'\s*,?$/)) return m[1]; // Single Quoted Text
                if (m = text.match(/^\s*(true|false)\s*,?$/)) return m[1] === "true"; // Boolean
                if (m = text.match(/^\s*((?:\+|\-)?\d+)\s*,?$/)) return parseInt(m[1]); // Integer Number
                if (m = text.match(/^\s*((?:\+|\-)?\d*\.\d*)\s*,?$/)) return parseFloat(m[1]); // Floating Number
                if (m = text.match(/^\s*(.*?)\s*,?$/)) return m[1]; // Unquoted Text
                return text;
              } );
              console.log(parsedData);
```

This is the CSV file that needs to be parsed. The first row is always the title

```
subject,contactName,contactEmail,contactPhoneNumber,dateStart,dateEnd,timeStart,timeEnd,isRecurring,frequency,days,location,room,visitorType,visitorName,visitorPhoneNumber,visitorEmail,licensePlate,sendInvite
Test CSV,name,example@example.com,+31 6 12345678,26-2-2021,26-2-2021,12:00,13:00,no,,"[]",Katrien NV,2A,Cursist,Dr. Doofenschmirtz,+31 6 98765432,visitor@example.email,,no
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this code is executed in a Cloud Function, you should use the "promise version" of the asynchronous [`download()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#download) method, as follows:

```
  if (folder == 'imports') {
    //Retrieve the file from firebase storage
    const storage = new Storage();
    const bucket = storage.bucket('gs://fmis-online-dev.appspot.com');
    return admin.storage().bucket().file(name). // <==!!! see the return here
      .download()
      .then(data => {
          const contents = data[0];
  
          // ....
          
          return null;   // <==!!! see the return here
      })
      .catch(error => {
         // ....
          return null;    // <==!!! see the return here
      })
   } else {
      return null;    // <==!!! see the return here
   }
```

You'll find in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) the explanation on why it is important to return a Promise, in order to correctly manage the life cycle of the Cloud Function.

---

You don't show how you write to Firestore, but you must include [in the Promises chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining) the Promises returned by the asynchronous Firestore methods, e.g.:

```
    return admin.storage().bucket().file(name). // <==!!! see the return here
      .download()
      .then(data => {
          const contents = data[0];
  
          // ....
          const parsedData = ....

          return admin.firestore()   // <==!!! see the return here
          .doc('xxx/yyyy').set( { parsedData, foo: bar });
      })
      .catch(error => {
         // ....
          return null;    // <==!!! see the return here
      })
```